# apply GPO only if specific user OU on specfic computer OU

Tags: active-directory, group-policy

The question is relatively simple:

how to apply a GPU (let's say folder redirection) only when a certain OU of users (e.g. employees) on a certain OU of computers (e.g. Desktops)?

the problem:

1. admins and other special users dont get folder redirections

   - so a loopback policy can't really work as that affects all users on a given computer-OU
2. Laptops dont get folder redirections

   - so a normal User Policy won't work either as that applies to that users regardless of where they log on.

are there ways in AD to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Use a loopback policy **combined** with security filtering based on membership in some group of users.

Assuming all your settings are 'user' settings.

- Link the policy with the computers
- In the security filtering remove the apply for 'authorized users', and add a group that only contains the users that you want the policy to apply to.

Comment: that sounds nice, I'll try that, thanks.
but also fun that now we switch from OUs to groups (no problem but it gets a bit chaotic keeping track of the internal workings of ADs when there are many ways of organizing stuff)